# Как сделать отправку HTML-письма с картинками через функцию mail в PHP?

Tags: email, php

На сайте после регистрации пользователя высылаются данные на почту в виде текста.
Можно ли сделать отправку в HTML-формате с изображениями в дизайне письма (не вложениями)?

Comment: > с изображениями в дизайне письма (не вложениями)?

Да, используя base64.

Насколько понимаю, swiftmailer позволяет делать это методом embed http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А я вот беру и советую очень удобный класс [php_libmail](http://webi.ru/webi_files/php_libmail.html)

Примеры работы там же на странице :)